# libGDX: Create a toolBar

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I whant to create a toolbar. If I click a icon a list should open. I use a Stack add containers (list for the icons) and add a Table to it. (So all gets scaled on resitze and no work needs to be done there)

But I cant set the X axis via container.setX(float). But the list has to open under the clicked Icon.

Is there a better way or a way to set the X without alingment?

```
private void rebuildStage() {
    VerticalGroup toolBar = buildToolBar();

    VerticalGroup vGroup = new VerticalGroup();
    vGroup.fill().setFillParent(true);
    vGroup.addActor(toolBar);

    clear();
    addActor(vGroup);
}

private VerticalGroup buildToolBar() {
    ImageButton btnFile = new ImageButton(Assets.instance.btn_skin, "file");
    ImageButton btnArrangement = new ImageButton(Assets.instance.btn_skin, "arrangement");
    ImageButton btnCollision = new ImageButton(Assets.instance.btn_skin, "collision");

    ButtonGroup<ImageButton> buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup<ImageButton>(btnFile, btnArrangement, btnCollision);
    buttonGroup.setMinCheckCount(0);

    Container<Table> tableFile = new Container<Table>(buildTableFile());
    tableFile.top().left();
    Container<Table> tableArrangement = new Container<Table>(buildTableArrangement());
    tableArrangement.top();
    Container<Table> tableCollision = new Container<Table>(buildTableCollision());
    tableArrangement.top();

    Stack stack = new Stack();
    stack.add(tableFile);
    stack.add(tableArrangement);
    stack.add(tableCollision);

    Table layer = new Table(Assets.instance.bg_skin);
    layer.setBackground("bg_table");
    layer.left();
    layer.add(btnFile).padLeft(10);
    layer.add(btnArrangement).padLeft(10);
    layer.add(btnCollision).padLeft(10);

    VerticalGroup vGroup = new VerticalGroup();
    vGroup.fill();
    vGroup.addActor(layer);
    vGroup.addActor(stack);
    return vGroup;
}

    private Table buildTableFile() {
    ImageButton button1 = new ImageButton(Assets.instance.btn_skin, "load");
    ImageButton button2 = new ImageButton(Assets.instance.btn_skin, "save");
    ImageButton button3 = new ImageButton(Assets.instance.btn_skin, "new");

    Table layer = new Table(Assets.instance.bg_skin);
    layer.setBackground("bg_table");
    layer.add(button1).pad(10, 10, 0, 10).row();
    layer.add(button2).pad(10, 10, 0, 10).row();
    layer.add(button3).pad(10, 10, 10, 10).row();
    return layer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a new stage for you toolbar **over** the stage you are having icons on.

All you need to do is to attach the **ClickListener** to the **toolbarStage** that will check what was the position of the click and render there the toolbar on **toolbarStage** - of course you can have another **ClickListener** that will on the old iconsStage that will set a variables set for a toolbar (I assume that its working is connected to which icon you have clicked).

```
Stage iconsStage;
Viewport iconsStageViewport;

Stage toolbarStage;
Viewport toolbarStageViewport;

public void prepareStages()
{
    ... //here you are creating iconsStage, filling it with actors etc...

    toolbarStage = new Stage();
    toolbarStageViewport = ... //create any viewport you need

    toolbarStage.setViewport(toolbarStageViewport );

    ... //now add to toolbarStage a proper listener and listeners to icons etc...
}

...

public void render()
{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    iconsStageViewport.update(this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight);
    iconsStage.act();
    iconsStage.draw();

    toolbarStageViewport.update(this.screenWidth, this.screenHeight);
    toolbarStage.act();
    toolbarStage.draw();
}
```

Please remember that **you cannot user more than one Stage without using [InputMultiplexer](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputMultiplexer.html)**. You can read about it more here:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling

Comment: Thanks 4 your awser. I found a other way: I just had to set: tableList.left.padLeft (offset). The container does not effect the table and just moved to right.